# Java: Setup GridWorld BugRunner in Linux

Tags: java

I'm quite new to Java, and I'm reading http://greenteapress.com/thinkjava.

I can't get to run the [GridWorld](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/apcourse/ap-computer-science-a/about-the-exam/gridworld-case-study) code.

following the instructions:

```
$ javac -classpath .:~/projects/GridWorldCode/gridworld.jar *.java
```

the above compiles without errors. When I execute the compiled code I get the following error:

```
$ java BugRunner      

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info/gridworld/actor/Actor
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.gridworld.actor.Actor
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

`java -cp .:/<path_to_your_gridworld_dir>/gridworld.jar: BugRunner`

Comment: Well you compiled with additional classes but you were trying to run it without them that is why ClassNotFoundException occured. In this command you add these classes to the classpath the same as during compilation.